# Remove app from google play store because of ( Violation of Metadata policy )

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, metadata

I have a serious problem . google play today was removed my Unity3d game from store and sent an email to me with this titled issue :

> Issue: Violation of Metadata policy

and In message text they said :

> The flagged content in your store listing relates to graphic violence
>   prominently depicted in app icons, promotional images, text, or
>   videos. Your store listing can be seen by all users (signed-in or not)
>   and needs to be appropriate for all audiences.

but I do not any of this !!!

I don't know what does it means ?!!
I just simply build my game and publish it in google play , but after few day they removed my app with this reason.

Also my game is free.

I searched all over the internet to find similar issue with another people, but I do not find any thing.

does any one know how can I solve this problem ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that your game description is not violating Google policies just write to them. You can contact them using live chat directly in the Play Developer Console. After explaining the problem, they will probably redirect you to "more technical" team and you will get an answer by e-mail. (Usually 1-3 days)

Comment: I thought about it for a while and realized that I had posted a site address and a telegram channel in the video I posted for my game. is that can be cause of this issue ?

Comment: a site address should not be a problem, as many developers have their changelog pages. I don't know what about telegram, but as far as it is in the video it should be fine.